# Remove header of a pdf using iText PdfCleanUpProcessor does not work

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to remove the headers of each page of an existing pdf using iText. Below is the function,

```
 public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
            List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();

            for(int i=1; i<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                    //System.out.println(i);
                    Rectangle mediabox = reader.getPageSize(i); 
                    cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(i, new Rectangle(0,800,1000,1000)));


            }
            PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);
            cleaner.cleanUp();
            stamper.close();
            reader.close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

This method removes headers from some pages. But does not remove from all the pages. Here is a sample pdf which does not render as expected.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4u8vupjqc4st3ib/love.pdf?dl=0

Comment: For your sample file I get a `org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException: Invalid marker found in entropy data`.

Comment: @mkl That's weird. I don't get any exceptions when I run the program. It just does not give the expected output.

Comment: From when is your apache commons imaging library?